# How to add custom image to replace default pin in iOS MKMapView via Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

So as of now, I just have the default MKMapView pin working. But I want a custom image to replace that little red pin. This is what I have below. What am I missing? I figured defining the view.image would do the trick, but I guess not.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:   
  (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]  
    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    view.enabled = YES;
    view.animatesDrop = YES;
    view.canShowCallout = YES;
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom-pin-image.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage         
     imageNamed:@"custom-image-for-annotation.png"]];
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView;
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:  
     UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, it has the image property but it ignores it an displays the default pin image instead.

You should use the `MKAnnotationView` instead.

Also, make sure that your `MKMapView` delegate hasn't been nilled.

Comment: Tat did the trick. Thanks. Is there a way to keep the "animateDrop" through for the custom image or no?

Comment: @MichaelSebastian Oh, I forgot to mention that you loose the animateDrop-function by going for the MKAnnoationView. Check out this answer for a solution with a custom MKAnnotationView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24060673/3655491